# Parsing information from content for database

Tags: php, mysql, regex, parsing, trim

I have a database table full of articles. In some cases, the bottom of the article has a block that I want to parse to get information from. For example, here are two possible values from the article table:

```
<p>Test test <blockquote class="pull">text quote</blockquote></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><span class="italic">italic text</span></p>

<div class="bottom-block"><div class="picture" style="background-image:url('/generator?f=somepicture.jpg');"></div><div class="blurb">Blurb about person<a href="http://website.com">http://website.com</a></div></div>
```

and another example:

```
<p>Some content</p>
<div class="bottom-block"><img alt="John Doe" class="picture" src="/assets/images/JOHN_DOE_1.jpg"><div class="blurb"><p>John Doe is a guy from Texas. <a href="http://johnswebsite.com" target="_blank">John's Website</a> and has a large following.</p></div></div>
```

The above are two examples of values seen in the database. Now, I want to be able to extract certain information. More precisely, I want to extract the Name, Url, ImageName, and Blurb

In the first example, after running a query on that value, I would like to see:

Name: 
Url: `http://website.com`
ImageName: `somepicture.jpg`
Blurb: `Blurb about person<a href="http://website.com">http://website.com</a>`

In the second example:

Name: `John Doe`
Url: `http://johnswebsite.com`
ImageName: `JOHN_DOE_1.jpg`
Blurb: `<p>John Doe is a guy from Texas. <a href="http://johnswebsite.com" target="_blank">John's Website</a> and has a large following.</p>`

I was playing around with an SQL query that is doing somewhat of a decent job, but still lots of inconsistency.

`SELECT id, url, content, TRIM(BOTH '\n' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '</div>\n</div>' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '</div></div>' FROM TRIM(SUBSTRING(content, LOCATE('class="bottom-block"',content)+18))))) as block_extract, TRIM(BOTH '\n' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '</div>\n</div>' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '</div></div>' FROM TRIM(SUBSTRING(content, LOCATE('class="blurb"',content)+12))))) as blurb FROM articles WHERE content LIKE '%bottom-block%' GROUP BY block_extract;`

Comment: Thats a _monstterr_ SQL statement.

Comment: Why is your question tagged PHP? Do you need a to do this inside the SQL statement, or can you use PHP to parse the data (which would obviously be wayyy easier)? More generally, in what context do you want to parse this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a DOM way:

```
$results = array();

$fields = array('name', 'img', 'url', 'blurb');

$queries = array('name'  => '//img/@alt',
                 'img'   => '//img[@class = "picture"]/@style |
                             //img/@src |
                             //div[@class = "picture"]/@style',
                 'url'   => '//div[@class = "blurb"]//a/@href',
                 'blurb' => '//div[@class = "blurb"]');

$imgPattern = <<<'EOD'
~
(?|
    .*? background-image:url\( [^)]*? ([^?="\')/]+ \.(?:png|jpe?g|gif) ).*
  | 
    .*? ([^=;/]+)$
)
~ix
EOD;

foreach ($data as $html) {
    $srcDom = new DOMDocument();
    @$srcDom->loadHTML($html);

    $elts = $srcDom->getElementsbyTagName("body")->item(0)->childNodes;

    $tmp['other'] = '';
    foreach ($elts as $elt) {
        if ( $elt->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE &&
             $elt->hasAttribute('class') &&
             $elt->getAttribute('class') == 'bottom-block' )
            $bbnode = $elt;
        else
            $tmp['other'] .= $srcDom->saveHTML($elt);
    }
    echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($other, true));
    if ( $bbnode ):
        $bbDom = new DOMDocument();
        $bbDom->appendChild($bbDom->importNode($bbnode, true));

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($bbDom);

        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $$field = $xpath->query($queries[$field]);

            if ( $field == 'blurb' ):
                $tmp[$field] = '';
                foreach ($$field->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
                    $tmp[$field] .= $bbDom->saveHTML($child);
                }
            else:
                $tmp[$field] = ($$field->length) ? $$field->item(0)->nodeValue : '';
            endif;
        }
        $tmp['img'] = preg_replace($imgPattern, '$1', $tmp['img']);
    endif;
    $results[] = $tmp;
}

echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($results, true));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have other cases where the image is coded as:

`<a href="#"><img class="picture" src="/generator?type=1&amp;w=80&amp;h=80&amp;f=picture.jpg"></a>`

How would I edit the preg_replace to match this as well?

Comment: Also, what sort of query could I add to the queries array to get the original HTML minus the "bottom-block" div.

For example, I was messing around with something like:
`$queries['original_content_without_blurb'] => '*[not(self::div[@class = "bottom-block"])]'`

Comment: Thanks Casimir, but the bb field contains the contents of 'bottom-block'. When in fact, I'd like the bb field to contain the original HTML minus the bottom-block div. Any ideas?

Comment: I have found yet another case for the image_name. Something like:
`<img class="picture" style="background-image:url('/imageGenerator?type=15&w=80&h=80&f=scotiabank.jpg');" />`
Sorry, I am not that great at RegEx or else I would try to add this one in myself. I feel like the current RegEx should capture this case since it's basically the difference between a "div" tag and "img" tag.

Comment: I figured out the image problem I was mentioning above:

`'image_name'   => '//img/@src | //img[@class = "picture"]/@style | //div[@class = "picture"]/@style',`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I do not know how one would go about doing this with an SQL query, but here's how I would do it with PHP.  The basic premise is to use five separate matching queries and then print them out.  The matching queries are as follows:

1. Bottom Block Contents
2. Images
3. URLS
4. Blurbs
5. Names

Here is some code to demonstrate.

```
// GET THE BOTTOM BLOCK CONTENT
preg_match('~(?<=<div class="bottom-block">).*?(?=</div>$)~ims', $mysql_row, $bottom_block_array);
$string = $bottom_block_array[0];

// GRAB THE IMAGES
preg_match_all('~[A-Z0-9_]+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png)(?=\'|")~i', $string, $images);
$images = $images[0];

// GRAB THE URLS
preg_match_all('~(?<=href=").*?(?=")~ims', $string, $urls);
$urls = $urls[0];

// GRAB THE BLURBS
preg_match_all('~(?<=<div class="blurb">).*?(?=</div>)~ims', $string, $blurbs);
$blurbs = $blurbs[0];

// GRAB THE NAMES
preg_match_all('~(?<=alt=").*?(?=")~ims', $string, $names);
$names = $names[0];



// LOOP THROUGH AND PRINT OUT ALL OF THE NAMES (OR ONLY ONE, IF DESIRED)
if ($names) {
    foreach ($names AS $name) {print "\nName: ".$name;} // USE THIS IF YOU WANT ALL OF THE NAMES
    // print "\nName: ".$names[0]; // USE THIS IF YOU ONLY WANT ONE POSSIBLE NAME TO SHOW UP
}
else {print "\nName:";}


if ($urls) {
    foreach ($urls AS $url) {print "\nUrl: ".$url;} // PRINT OUT ALL URLS
    // print "\nUrl: ".$urls[0]; // PRINT OUT ONLY ONE URL    
}
else {print "\nUrl:";}


if ($images) {
    foreach ($images AS $image) {print "\nImageName: ".$image;} // PRINT OUT ALL THE IMAGES
    // print "\nImageName: ".$images[0]; // PRINT OUT ONLY ONE IMAGE
}
else {print "\nImageName:";}


if ($blurbs) {
    foreach ($blurbs AS $blurb) {print "\nBlurb: ".$blurb;} // PRINT OUT ALL OF THE BLURBS
    // print "\nBlurb: ".$blurbs[0]; // PRINT OUT ONLY ONE BLURB
}
else {print "\nBlurb:";}


print "\n\n\n\n\n";
```

[Here is a working demo](http://ideone.com/AubIKP)